# Why am I getting an "expected string or bytes-like object" when tokenizing?

Tags: nltk

I am a newbie in Python and I read and execute codes carefully. However, I found it hard to solve this basic problem. I always encounter "expected string or bytes-like object", when I tried to tokenize using nltk and pandas dataframe. Somehow, I tried to convert my text to string because of it but I get the same results.

This is my code:

`df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\nec_2\Documents\data_finalSLCA.csv', sep ='\t', encoding='utf-8', delimiter=",") print(df)`

#extracting only the column abstract

`df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['abstract'])`

#converting to list
`df_2 = [t for t in df.abstract.tolist()]`

#tokenizing

`from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize`
`data = df_2`
`tokenized_text=word_tokenize(data)`
`print(tokenized_text)`
`print(type(tokenized_text))`

I am getting error like "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".

Can somebody help me out with the problem?

Thanks in advance.